# unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do and user prompt not working

Tags: ruby

In addition to the error in the title, I also get:

> C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Wyncode/unterminated string meets end of file.rb:20: syntax error, unexpected ( arg, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
>       puts ("zombies are in the castle gr...
>             ^
>   [Finished in 0.3s with exit code 1]

Also when I am prompting the user for answers my terminal is not asking me for an answer before continuing.

Here is my code:

```
name.Capitalize = {"1" => "Mario",
        "2" => "Luigi",
        "3" => "Kirby",
        }
    puts "Zombie apocalypse"
    puts "will you survive?"

def character (prompt, options)
    puts = "who will you be?"
    options = "Mario, Trump, Fox"
    character = gets.chomp.downcase
until options.include? character
end
end

puts "ok #{name} all three of you run out of peach's castle which has been overrun"

if character = #{Mario} || #{Luigi} || #{kirby}
    puts ("zombies are in the castle grounds, there are weapons over the bridge")
    puts "What do you do, charge through or sneak?"
    x = gets.chomp.downcase
            if x == "sneak"
                puts "oh you died"
            if x == "charge through"
                puts "the zombies tumbled over the bridge's edge, you made it safe and sound"
            else
                puts "you did nothing and were eaten alive by Princess Peach"
        end
    end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What have I done wrong on line 20?

Comment: and why when i plug this into the terminal does this not prompt for a answer  at 'character=gets.chomp'? p.s. i started learning to code a week ago

Comment: I will expand this story but I need to know why it isn't working now before i continue with this action adventure style game.

Comment: The error is not on line 20, it's on line 19: the entire line after the equals sign is commented out, as you can clearly see by the syntax highlighting in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On line 20 you've used:

```
    puts ("zombies are in the castle grounds, there are weapons over the bridge")
```

It can be fixed in 2 ways:

Either :

```
    puts "zombies are in the castle grounds, there are weapons over the bridge"
```

Or:

```
    puts("zombies are in the castle grounds, there are weapons over the bridge")
```

Even though, it would help you get rid of that particular error, there would be other errors popping up one after the other. Why? Because, there're a number of mistakes in your code.

I admire your enthusiasm. You're in your first week of learning programming, and you're already on your way to developing an action adventure game, wow. Sadly, no amount of passion could help you achieve anything, unless you learn the basics of your craft. I'd suggest that you should get a good book on Ruby. Read it properly and get the concepts right.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will go over the codecademy course again and buy a book. :)